When can we divide a shape into n equal parts (like Gauss and Abel)?
Gauss' theorem on the constructibility of the regular n-gon is very famous. I recently came across the similar theorem by Abel on dividing the lemniscate into n equal parts, and wondered if there are any other shapes/values of complex functions which admit a similar characterisation using Galois theory?
For reference, in both results this is possible if and only if $n=2^m p_1p_2...p_k$ where the $p_i$ are distinct Fermat primes.

http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf

For the cardioid $r=1-\cos\theta$, the counterclockwise arc length from the cusp to any point is determined by calculus to be
$4[1-\cos(\theta/2)]; 0\le\theta\le2\pi$
versus a full perimeter of $8$ (taking $\theta=2\pi$).
From this formulation it is seen that the cardioid can be divided into any number of equal parts.
